# "Touch to download SoundCloud" notification

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung, notification-bar

I have Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.3. Not rooted.

From time to time, I get notification: "Touch to download SoundCloud"

[image: Touch to download SoundCloud]

I did had Soundcloud installed application before, but I have uninstalled it and I am still getting this notification. When I tap it, nothing happens.

Does anyone know what this notification is or how can I identify which process is spawning notification?

**Edit:**

I have found that process that is raising this notification is Firefox. Every time I start Firefox on the phone I get this notification. The question is, how to stop this notification  from displaying when I start Firefox?

Comment: It's no use editing your question to ask a new question, as your question's already been answered. Best to ask a new question, then people will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the app responsible by long-tapping the notification and clicking "App info" on the pop-up menu.